# C# Textbox to Update/Edit Data on XML

Tags: c#, xml, textbox, edit

```
    public void EditStudentRecord(string OldStudent, string NewStudent)
    {
        string strFilename = "Student_" + Tools.IDStudent + ".xml";
        if (File.Exists(strFilename))
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"Student_" + Tools.IDStudent + ".xml");
            var query = from p in xml.Elements(strFilename).Elements("Student Name")

                        where (string)p.Element("Name") == OldStudent
                        select p;

            foreach (var record in query)

            {
                record.Element("Name").Value = NewStudent;
            }

            xml.Save(strFilename);
        }
    }
```

The Code Above will Update/Edit The Data on My XML File `< Name >` through A ComboBox Option with `txtName.Text` to Update the New Name

When I Edit The Name Abu Khan into Khan Han

this is the xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Student_1.xml>
   <Student Name>
         <Name>Abu Khan</Name>         
         <Address>India</Address>
         <Grade>87</Grade>
   </Student Name>
</Student_1.xml>
```

and the Output xml file once edited

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Student_1.xml>
   <Student Name>
         <Name>Khan Han</Name>         
         <Address>India</Address>
         <Grade>87</Grade>
   </Student Name>
</Student_1.xml>
```

Now my problem is how to update also the `< Address >` and the `< Grade >` data on XML using 
2 textboxes, `txtAddress.Text` for Address and `txtGrade.Text` for Grade

can someone please help me modify my code above so that i can also edit/update the `< address >` and `< grade >`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier approach:

Represent the XML data as an object

```
public class Student
{
  public  string Name;
  public  string Address;
  public  string Grade;
}
```

Deserialize the object

```
Student student; 
 using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("pathToXMLFile"))
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
    student = (Student)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
}
```

Bind the object to your controls on the WinForm

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", student, "Name");
```

Serialize the object to save the changes

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("yourFilePath"))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
}
```

Comment: im not used to code like yours sir, im little bit confused of your codes, i dont know how to use it, if you dont mind sir, kindly just modify my codes so that i can directly apply it!! im new at C# so thats why i dont know how to use your code above and where to put that codes on my codes